# Problem using multiple async/await to copy files

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have a `DataGrid` populated by a list where the items have the source and target direction to copy the file in a zip.

This is the code in a button where I did the cycle for each item of `DataGrid` to start with parallel copying.

```
var row_list = GetDataGridRows(dgwStation);
tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

//All items of DataGrid
foreach (DataGridRow single_row in row_list)
{
    var row = single_row.GetIndex();
    tasks.Add(TaskOperationBackupOffline(row, tokenSource.Token));
}

btBackup.IsEnabled = false; 
btCancel.IsEnabled = true; 

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); //Wait all the tasks are finished
```

This is the code of `TaskOperationBackupOffline`:

```
private async Task<string> TaskOperationBackupOffline(int rowindex, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        //Read all the datas
        string source=StationItemsList[rowindex].ControlPath,
            target = StationItemsList[rowindex].Destination,
            filename = StationItemsList[rowindex].StationName;

        //Source directory control
        StationItemsList[rowindex].State = Chiavi.dict["backupon_controlorigin"].ToString();
        dgwStation.Items.Refresh();

        //If the source not exist, exit 
        if (Directory.Exists(source) == false)
        {
            StationItemsList[rowindex].State = Chiavi
                .dict["backupstate_source"].ToString();
            dgwStation.Items.Refresh();
            generalerror = true;
            return "source error";
        }

        //Target directory control
        StationItemsList[rowindex].State = Chiavi.dict["backupon_controldestinationdata"].ToString();
        dgwStation.Items.Refresh();

        //If not exist I create it
        if (Directory.Exists(target) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
        }

        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) //Cancellation by user
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        StationItemsList[rowindex].State = Chiavi.dict["backupon_preparation"].ToString();
        dgwStation.Items.Refresh();

        string nome1 = target + "\\";
        nome1 += DateTime.Now.Year;
        nome1 += "-";
        nome1 += voidGeneral.ConversioneDecimale(DateTime.Now.Month);
        nome1 += "-";
        nome1 += voidGeneral.ConversioneDecimale(DateTime.Now.Day);
        nome1 += "_";
        nome1 += voidGeneral.ConversioneDecimale(DateTime.Now.Hour);
        nome1 += "_";
        nome1 += voidGeneral.ConversioneDecimale(DateTime.Now.Minute);
        nome1 += "_";
        nome1 += voidGeneral.ConversioneDecimale(DateTime.Now.Second);
        nome1 += "-";
        nome1 += filename;

        nomearchivio = nome1 + ".zip";

        // Name of zip file with all the path
        ArchivioB1.FileName = nome1 + ".zip";
        // Create archive
        ArchivioB1.OpenArchive(System.IO.FileMode.Create);

        ArchivioB1.Comment = rowindex.ToString(); 

        ArchivioB1.OnOverallProgress += new BaseArchiver
            .OnOverallProgressDelegate(ArchivioB1_OnOverallProgress);

        // Source directory 
        ArchivioB1.BaseDir = source;

        StationItemsList[rowindex].State = Chiavi.dict["backupon_createZIP"].ToString();
        dgwStation.Items.Refresh();

        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) //Cancellation by user
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        // Copy all files in the zip archive
        ArchivioB1.AddFiles("*.*");

        // Close zip file
        ArchivioB1.CloseArchive();

        await Task.Delay(50);

        return "Complete";
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        StationItemsList[rowindex].State = "Cancelled";
        dgwStation.Items.Refresh();
        tbkStato.Text = Chiavi.dict["backupstate_cancelled"].ToString();
        return "Cancelled";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StationItemsList[rowindex].State = ex.Message.ToString();
        dgwStation.Items.Refresh();
        generalerror = true;
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

When I click the button the UI immediately freeze than isn't async and at the end is processed only the first item.

What I did wrong?

Comment: The `TaskOperationBackupOffline` method is not truly asynchronous. The only asynchronous operation it contains is the `await Task.Delay(50);` at the end. What is the intention of this line? Also the `StationItemsList` variable is not defined in your code, so it is impossible for us to run your code and reproduce the issue. Ideally you should post the minimal code required in order to reproduce the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the async keyword to a method does not make it run asynchronously. It only means that the method can be awaited - you may want to look up what that actually means. To make the method run non-blocking you have to wrap the entire content in something like

```
return Task.Run(() => 
{
    // your code goes here 
});
```

Then the logic will actually run on a different thread.

Once you are no longer on the UI-thread, you won't be able to call methods on UI elements directly. You will have to use [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=net-5.0).

Comment: could you be more clear?